# Android NDK: How to get compiler architecture in Android.mk dynamically

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to configure Android.mk to cross compile native code to support different chipset namely armeabi, mips, and x86. I know I can configure Application.mk in the following way to compile the source code for different chip set:

```
APP_ABI := all
```

This will trigger Android-NDK's build script to compile the source code for all the chipsets. However, I want to dynamically tell Android.mk to look for different static library dependencies compiled with different chip set.

```
# Get the architecture info
ARCH := ????

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE:= mylib
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= build/lib/libxxx_$(ARCH).a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Is this possible to do? If so, can anyone advice how to do so?

> **Update**: I tried something like this in Application.mk:
>
> ```
>  APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips x64
> ```
>
> with Android.mk:
>
> ```
> # Get the architecture info
> ARCH := $(APP_ABI)
>
> include $(CLEAR_VARS)
> LOCAL_MODULE:= mylib
> LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= build/lib/libxxx_$(ARCH).a
> LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)
> include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
> ```
>
> but it errors with the following:
>
> ```
>  The LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt static library should only contain one item
> ```
>
> which makes sense. I want to pass APP_ABI := all in Application.mk and be able to
>   dynamically reference it. Any ideas?

Comment: If you look at ndk and other libs, they use defines such as `#ifdef __arm__` but I am not sure where it's defined or standardized

Comment: Hi , i want to do exactly the same thing. Can you give me example of Andorid.mk file and where to put it in the app??

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is `TARGET_ARCH` variable that holds the value of the current ABI being built. You can use it the following way:

```
ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),x86)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS   := $(COMMON_FLAGS_LIST)
else
    LOCAL_CFLAGS   := -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp $(COMMON_FLAGS_LIST)
endif
```

If you specify `APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a armeabi mips x86` or `APP_ABI := all` in your `Application.mk` you will get each and every separate ABI value.

Comment: Hello Sergey, thanks for the answer. It worked like a charm! I also appreciate how you gave me an example on how I can better use this as well. I was also getting fp warning when compiling but this also resolved that warning as well :)

Comment: FYI, not sure if u intended your code as extra help but I tried anyway because I was curious :) LOCAL_CFLAGS   := -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp. I observed that it errors while compiling mips architecture, it errored with the following:cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-mfpu=vfp"
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-mfloat-abi=softfp". This means the correct code snippet would be LOCAL_CFLAGS would be ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),arm)
    LOCAL_CFLAGS   := -mfpu=vfp -mfloat-abi=softfp $(COMMON_FLAGS_LIST)
else
    LOCAL_CFLAGS   := $(COMMON_FLAGS_LIST). 
endif. Right?

Comment: Doesn't work for arm64-v8a, which returns arm64 instead. The other answer (TARGET_ARCH_ABI) is correct.

Comment: @Karu: this was answered 2.5 years ago. There was no arm64-v8a in sight at that time.

Comment: That's fine, but I read it yesterday. It was incorrect yesterday, so I downvoted it yesterday.

Comment: armeabi-v7a and armeabi-v7 are both returning arm with TARGET_ARCH. armeabi-v7a was in sight at that time.

Answer (score 36):

Check `TARGET_ARCH_ABI`:

```
ifeq($(TARGET_ARCH_ABI), armeabi-v7a)
  # v7a-specific stuff
endif
```

Comment: $TARGET_ARCH_ABI simply returns whatever I set in APP_ABI. Is there any way I can pass either APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips x64 or APP_ABI := all?

Comment: You must set `APP_ABI := all` in `Application.mk`, otherwise `ndk-build` will only use the default `armeabi` architecture. For multiple architectures, NDK will iteratively call your `Android.mk` file - every time setting `$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)` differently.

Comment: I thought he was setting `APP_ABI` in `Android.mk`, but I misread. Sorry.

Comment: `ifneq (,$(filter $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI),armeabi armeabi-v7a))` for multi archs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656425/makefile-ifeq-logical-or