# compiling the android source code so that it generates .so file specific to 64 bit ubuntu platform instead of arm 32 bit .so

Tags: android, ubuntu

I want to use .so file of android but its built for arm 32 bit architecture. I am using ubuntu 64 bit environment.

```
Error I got : wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

I know i have to generate. so specific to 64-bit ubuntu arch. The main problem is I am new to make files and there are so many make files in android.Even i saw build. mk & environment. mk of android. I got the fact that android can be built for

```
1.arm
2.MIPS
3.x86 arch
```

I don't know what n all make files needs to be changed so that I can configure for 64bit linux environment . **Please give some idea what n all needs to be changed in make files...?**

Note: I also know Apart from make files there are many other dependencies specific to each platform.
**Please provide me from where I can start & exactly where they will specify target platform in android**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `APP_ABI := x64` ?

Comment: @ asloob APP_ABI will be in which file ...can u specify in which make file or shell script? in android source code. Explain in detail please

Comment: refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614417/android-ndk-how-to-get-compiler-architecture-in-android-mk-dynamically

Comment: in specific i want to generate core libraries of android for example libcutils.so etc for x86_64...can i do it with android build system?