# pass parameters from C++ to Assembly in android

Tags: android, gcc, assembly, java-native-interface, arm

I am trying to pass more than four parameters from my C++ code to Assembly.

The C++ function looks like :

```
static float armFunction(float, float, float, float, float);
```

I can retrieve the first four parameters from the registers r0-r3 without any problem.

I expect that my fifth float argument is on the stack  and i should be able to access it using the stack pointer sp e.g. I try to load my fifth argument in r4 like :

```
ldr r4, [sp]
```

or even:

```
ldr r4, [sp, #-0x4]
```

But this doesn't work and the assembly code immediately exits with some stack corruption output.

My complete assembly code looks like this here: http://pastie.org/3933875

Comment: Usually the easiest way to do it right is to write a simple C function, then compile and disassemble it.  Presto - instant example code.

Comment: I would simply use the [inline assembler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) with the names of the parameters.

Comment: Hi Carl, 
Thanks for your idea. I disassembled my simple C function with five arguments and it looks like that the gcc compiler with NDK does'nt add the 5th argument to the stack. It only loads first four argument and the 5th is completely ignored for the assemlby function. Isnt that surprising ? See the disassembley here http://pastie.org/3934223

Comment: Look closely. Your 5th argument is setup in ip (line 15 and 22) and then stored on the stack in line 27.

Comment: Also, ldr r4, [sp, #-0x4] will never work. Your stack grows from Top to bottom, so your values will either be ON the stack pointer or ABOVE it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My asm code has no trouble reading the 5th parameter from a JNI call from C to asm. Here are the first 2 lines of my asm function:

```
  stmfd    sp!,{r4-r12,lr}
  ldr      r12,[sp,#40]   @ first stack variable
```

In the case where you're not needing to preserve any registers, the 5th parameter is on the top of the stack:

```
  ldr r12,[sp]
```

Comment: i prefer moving the stack variables from stack first using simply, 
ldr r6, [sp] 

becoz apart from r4, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, i found that it is not necessary to save the rest of the registers....

Comment: The code I copied this from does need to save the registers, I only push/pop the minimum necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that is modifies r4 without restoring it. The parameter is on the top of the stack.

Comment: why is modifying r4 a problem ?
is there something important in that register which will corrupt the stack or program-counter PC ?

Comment: R0-R3 and R12 can be trashed, R4-R11,R13 must be preserved