# Run Machine Code On Android Devices?

Tags: android, assembly, machine-code

Is Way To Run Machine Code Instead Android OS In Android Devices ?

I Want Remove Android Os And Work With Cpu And Other Devices Directly .

What Compiler I Can Use ?

Comment: phones are just computers, so if you can install your own bootloader, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: Good luck removing Android OS

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561509/compiling-assembly-for-android, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390509/linking-android-c-code-and-arm-assembler ?

Comment: Maybe for Android devices which use x86 CPU.

Answer (score 0):

MASM is an x86 assembler, so it would not be suitable for most Android devices as the vast majority use ARM-based processors.

That said, Android phones are computers just like any other and can be programmed in assembly. The first thing you'll need to do is select a device running a well documented CPU and chipset.

Since you'll be removing Android and plan on programming in assembly you'll need to write your own routines for nearly everything. An understanding of the CPU, power management and some form of I/O (you can avoid having to write complex display code if you plan to interface with the phone through serial communication, for example).

Unfortunately, much of the information required for successfully writing your own OS for an Android device is unavailable so you'll need some hardware analysis tools to assist in reverse engineering some of this information. A logic analyzer may be useful in sniffing some of the protocols used between chips, although much of modern phones is done on a single SoC, so you'll need to experiment heavily and compile information from a wide variety of online sources.

Aside from that, it's smooth sailing. Programming an OS in assembly for Android is pretty much the same as programming an OS in assembly for any other computer and you'll find it to be rather familiar territory.

Comment: What Is Good Documented Cpu ? Where Can Get Mediatek CPU Document ? I Can Get Them From Mediatek Company ?